# Setting connection string with username and password in ASP.Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working on my first ASP.NET Core MVC application.What is the right way to specify the connection string in a ASP.NET Core MVC application with a sql server backend requiring sql authentication?

> ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'userid'.\

Below is my appsettings.json file. When I run the application, it throws an error.

```
{
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "InstrumentationKey": ""
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
      "DefaultConnection": "Server=myserver;Database=mydatabase;userid=id;password=mypwd"
  },
    "Logging": {
      "IncludeScopes": false,
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Debug",
        "System": "Information",
        "Microsoft": "Information"
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 98, accepted):

`User Id` is the correct way, with space in the middle

> Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
> Password=myPassword;

https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Answer (score 49):

That's because the correct keyword is `User Id`, as shown in the following example:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;password=myPassword;Trusted_Connection=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;"
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

Please try this followingcode one: with latest Visual Studio 2022 it works

```
"ConnectionStrings": "Server=ServerAddress;Database=DatabaseName;User Id=User;password=Password;Trusted_Connection=SSPI;Encrypt=false;TrustServerCertificate=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;"
```

Answer (score 4):

Can you try `User ID` instead of `userid`?

Note the main difference is in the space between `user` and `id`, the case doesn't matter

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "MvcMovieContext": "Server=localhost\\NOMINSTANCE;Database=NomBD;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;User ID=sa;Password=password1;Integrated Security=False"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please write bellow code in dbcontext file

```
 protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(
                    @"Server =.; Database = MyDb; User id=uid; Password=pwd; Trusted_Connection = True; MultipleActiveResultSets = true"
                );
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -2):

By setting Integrated `security = false` in your connection string in `web.config` file then this error will be solved